# Search result using keyword

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

This is my SQL Server table

```
productCodeId   varchar(15) 
productName varchar(60) 
productKeyword  varchar(MAX)
```

In `productKeyword` I store multiple keyword like below example

```
1   Product1   website,software,sms 
2   Product2   Software,sms
3   Product3   sms,website
```

Now I want to search any keyword like "website" it will display me result of Product1 and product3

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE productKeyword LIKE '%website%'` or even better use full text index/normalize data(CSV in column)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    *
FROM      Table T
WHERE     productKeyword LIKE '%website%'
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for more info on `like`

By the way, you shouldn't put multiple values in a cell. Read up on normalization.